# Страница ошибки 404 yii2

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, как сделать свою страницу ошибки в yii2.
Создал view error.php во views/site. В контроллере прописал

```
public function actionError()
{
    $this->render('error');
}
```

В config/web.php

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
]
```

Но при вызове

```
throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404 ,'Страница не найдена');
```

переадресация на страницу ошибки не происходит, отображается страница ошибки браузера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контроллерах, где планируется выбрасывать нужную страницу ошибки, в методе actions или behaviors у Вас должно быть прописано

```
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            ... // тут еще какие-то опции могут быть
        ];
    }
```

В конфиге Вы все прописали правильно

В контроллере Вам не нужен метод `public function actionError()`

Соответственно, если Вы хотите "искусственно" вызвать ошибку, то и выбрасывать нужно `throw new \yii\web\ErrorAction(404 ,'Страница не найдена');` или `throw new yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('Страница не найдена');`

Comment: С ErrorAction ошибка, но с NotFoundHttpException все отлично. Спасибо!